# Laravel SSL read operation timed out | Swift_IoException | PHP bug?

Tags: php, email, ssl, laravel, swiftmailer

### I have an error in Laravel 4:

> ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) fgets(): SSL read operation timed out

```
156.     * @return string
157.     *
158.     * @throws Swift_IoException
159.     */
160.    public function readLine($sequence)
161.    {
162.        if (isset($this->_out) && !feof($this->_out)) {
163.            $line = fgets($this->_out);
164.            if (strlen($line) == 0) {
165.                $metas = stream_get_meta_data($this->_out);
```

This error refers to SendGrid. My Laravel settings are default:

`laravel>app>config>mail.php`

```
<?php

array(
  'driver' => 'smtp',
  'port' => 465,        
  'encryption' => 'ssl',
  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
)
```

How to solve it?

(see also: [Laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/10-07-2014-fgets-ssl-read-operation-timed-out))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

I have found a solution but it is not the best way. For testing it is ok:)

When I uploaded my application to the cloud, I get the error. 
On the domain, I have turned off the SSL. In `laravel>app>config>mail.php`, I have changed this:

```
<?php

array(
  'driver' => 'smtp',
  'port' => 25, //earlier: 465     
  'encryption' => '', //earlier: 'ssl'
  //other settings
)
```

---

### Solution 2

Probably it's this bug in PHP 5.4.33 / 5.5.17 ([link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68046)). You have to downgrade to version 5.4.32. Then it should work.

```
yum downgrade $(rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\n" | grep ^php | awk '{print $1"-5.4.32"}') -y
```

See also [laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/10-07-2014-fgets-ssl-read-operation-timed-out).

---

### Solution 3

Solution 3 is really simple, turn off all SSL on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Now that an update is available, another solution would be to upgrade PHP to v5.5.18:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope this helps.